# Extracting value from collection in typescript giving error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to retrieve all the product types from the collection in my angular 7 application and access it in html. I am getting error ProductType of undefined. Is my property wrong. If you see below the object is an array of arrays. Each array would contain the same product Type For example as seen in the screenshot Strategic Partnerships is the same for the first array , Comingled Fund is the same for second array. I finally need list which would contain unique values to iterate in the UI. So the values that i would pass be [Strategic Partnerships , Comingled Fund etc etc]

component

```
get MissingProductKeys() {
    return this.AllocationDetails.MissingProducts.map(({ProductType}) => ProductType);
}
```

UI

```
  <div *ngIf="MissingProductKeys">
        <div  *ngFor="let productType of MissingProductKeys">
            <div>{{productType.ProductType}}</div>

        </div>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let group of AllocationDetails.MissingProducts">


                     <tr><br/></tr>

                   <tr *ngFor="let post of group">

                        <td>{{post.ProductName}}</td>

                    </tr>
            </ng-container>

    </div>
    </div>
```

JSON - AllocationDetails.MissingProducts

```
[[{"ProductId":2844,"ProductName":"*DO NOT USE* City Plan LLC","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2840,"ProductName":"*DO NOT USE* Baha'i Separate Managed Account","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2851,"ProductName":"EnTrustPermal Special Opportunities Evergreen Fund Ltd.","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2852,"ProductName":"EnTrustPermal Spafid Multi-Strategy Fund","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"}],[{"ProductId":2745,"ProductName":"EnTrust Special Opportunities Fund III Master LP","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2854,"ProductName":"EnTrustPermal Select Opportunities II Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2746,"ProductName":"EnTrust Structured Income Fund I Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2749,"ProductName":"EnTrust Structured Income Fund II Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2778,"ProductName":"EnTrustPermal Structured Income Fund II-A Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2794,"ProductName":"EnTrustPermal Hedge Fund Opportunities II Ltd. Continuing","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"}],[{"ProductId":2828,"ProductName":"ICBC Quantitative HengSheng Choice Pooled Fund.","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2853,"ProductName":"HEC SPV II Cayman LP","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2800,"ProductName":"TP ETP Offshore LP","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2829,"ProductName":"ICBC Quantitative Xincheng Choice Pooled Fund Trust.","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":1841,"ProductName":"Brightgate Absolute Return FIL","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "}],[{"ProductId":2827,"ProductName":"EnTrustPermal Alternative Income Strategy.","ProductType":"Liquid Alternatives"},{"ProductId":1603,"ProductName":"EnTrustPermal Alternative Core Fund","ProductType":"Liquid Alternatives"}]]
```

Array

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used destructor in map cb. So from [{ ProductType: "exampleString" }] you will get ["exampleString"].

And when you iterate `MissingProductKeys` you calling `ProductType` attribute. String has to `ProductType` attr so it will return `undefined`.

to fix that you should change html to

```html
<div *ngFor="let productType of MissingProductKeys">
    <div>{{productType}}</div>
</div>
```

----- Edited -----

Structure is

```js
Array<Array<{
      "ProductId": number,
      "ProductName": string
      "ProductType": string
}>
```

So .map with destructor on ProductType will return undefined because array has no ProductType attribute.

If you want to received Array you have apply `.flat()` method before map with destructor

E.g.

```js
get MissingProductKeys() {
    return this.AllocationDetails.MissingProducts.flat().map(({ProductType}) => ProductType);
}
```

or

```js
get MissingProductKeys() {
    return this.AllocationDetails.MissingProducts.flatMap(({ProductType}) => ProductType);
}
```

-----Edited2-----

Set is collection that doesn't have duplicated items, so when you map array into set all duplicates will disappear e.g. `let arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']` then parse it to set `let set = new Set(arr)` and set is Set<'a', 'b', 'c'>, but we want to have array not set so we have to converse it into array by `return Array.from(set.values());` so returned value will be `["a", "b", "c"]`

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Set)

Comment: So you mean I need to do only a html change. Nothing is printing yet

Comment: If i do this i getting the correct length of 4   Missing product length   {{MissingProductKeys.length}}

Comment: in the debug console, when i execute this this.AllocationDetails.MissingProducts.map(({ProductType}) => ProductType) , it returns an array containing four elements of  undefined

Comment: Tu will return something like this: `['Strategic Partnership', 'Strategic Partnerships' ...]` so it will not be uniq. To remove duplicates you can use `Set` type for example: `let set = new Set(arr);  return Array.from(set.values());` where array is yours `return this.AllocationDetails.MissingProducts.flat().map(({ProductType}) => ProductType);` that will return list of uniq strings from your json.

Comment: Sorry not very clear about the unique logic. Could you update the answer please

Comment: Thank you so much. Just to let you know this worked MissingProducts.flat().map and not this this.AllocationDetails.MissingProducts.flatMap. Dont know why